# No module named 'urls' no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou estudando sobre divisão de URLs em Django e não consigo fazer o direcionamento do meu arquivo de url principal para o secundário.

Rastreamento:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PASTA DO CRISTHIAN\MOOC\Scripts\simplemooc\simplemooc\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('urls')),
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\PASTAD~1\MOOC\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

Arquivo de URLs principal:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from simplemooc.core import views
from simplemooc.core import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Arquivo de URL secundário:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from simplemooc.core import views   

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contato/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Erro:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urls'
```

Poderiam ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pela mensagem, seu módulo urls não está podendo ser importado por algum motivo, vamos criar um projeto minimalista para vc ver como funciona:

Crie em um diretório temporário um projeto django:

```
$ django-admin startproject hello
```

Vá para o diretorio do projeto e crie uma app chamada core:

```
$ cd hello
$ django-admin startproject hello
```

Edite o arquivo `hello/settings.py` e, na seção `INSTALLED_APPS` acrescente a app criada, devendo ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]
```

Edite o arquivo urls.py no diretório do projeto (hello/urls.py) para que fique com o seguinte conteudo:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^core/', include('core.urls', namespace='core', app_name='core'))
]
```

crie um diretorio para as templates em core:

```
$ mkdir -p core/templates/core
```

crie uma template em core chamada hello.html, com o conteudo

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Crie (ou edite), na reaiz da app core, o arquivo urls.py com o conteudo

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from core .views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello/$', hello,  name='hello'),
]
```

Crie a suas views (views.py) no diretori da app (core) com o conteudo:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def hello(request):
    return render(request, 'core/hello.html')
```

Finalmente rode o projeto, aponte o browser para http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/hello/ e veja Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invez de voce fazer dessa forma:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from simplemooc.core import views
from simplemooc.core import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Remova as aspas e faca assim:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from simplemooc.core import views
from simplemooc.core import urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Por que uma vez que vc fez import delas voce pode passa-las sem as aspas